# PHP: Regex to replace dash only if there are specific word and number before it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace a dash between two time values and replace it with the word `to` but only if before the first time value there is the word `from`

This is what I have until now, which works fine, but it matches all the cases where there are two timeframes with a dash between them.

```
$text = "The Spa center works 08:00-20:30 every day";
$text = preg_replace('/(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})/','$1 to $2', $text);
```

And what I want it to trigger only if the sentence looks like that

**The Spa center works `from` 08:00-20:30 every day**

So the desired result should be

**The Spa center works from 08:00 `to` 20:30 every day**

**Final Solution**

Thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew help, the final solution, will match also Unicode and spaces between the two timeframes and the dash looks like that.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bfrom\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*\K-(?=\s*\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?!\d))/u','$1 to $2', $text);
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this is also matching all the cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('/\bfrom\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}\K-(?=\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?!\d))/',' to ', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZiIdBP/1)

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `from` - a word `from`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace
- `\d{1,2}:\d{2}` - one or two digits, `:`, two digits
- `\K` - omit the matched text
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?!\d))` - immediately on the right, there must be one or two digits, `:`, two digits not followed with another digit.

Comment: just one more question. If the word is not `from`, but another language that is Unicode? For example instead of `from`, to be `от`. How can I do that?

Comment: @lStoilov You will need a `u` flag, e.g. with Russian: `'/\bс\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}\K-(?=\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?!\d))/u'`. Fortunately, word boundaries in PHP are Unicode-aware when the `u` flag is used.

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work... But it was my bad... I had a typo. Now it worked correctly

Comment: one last question... what if the times are written with a space before and after the dash. Like this `08:00-20:30`

Comment: @lStoilov `'/\bс\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*\K-(?=\s*\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?!\d))/u'`

Answer (score 0):

You may include the `from` keyword in your regex pattern:

```php
$text = "The Spa center works from 08:00-20:30 every day";
$text = preg_replace('/\bfrom (\d{1,2}:\d{2})-(\d{1,2}:\d{2})/','from $1 to $2', $text);
echo $text;  // The Spa center works from 08:00 to 20:30 every day
```

Comment: This is working but also removes the word from. So it becomes `The Spa center works 08:00 to 20:30 every day`

Comment: You could capture `from ` too since that should be in the output `\b(from \d{1,2}:\d{2})-(\d{1,2}:\d{2})`